# Installing Ubuntu help

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, partitioning, 13.04, windows-xp

I have a PC with 2 HDDs, and want to install Ubuntu 13.04 . Unfortunately, my active partition is *not* on my Windows XP partition. I assume my drive list when boot from LiveUSB similar like this:

```
/dev/sda
 /dev/sda1 (active partition)
 /dev/sda2 (empty drive)
/dev/sdb
 /dev/sdb1 (Windows XP system)
 /dev/sdb2 (Data)
 /dev/sdb3 (Data)
```

All of that is MBR disk.

Where I should install Ubuntu and GRUB?

Answer (score 0):

At first, every hard drive may have its own active partition.

You do not really need grub. During the boot, in bios, you may press some key and select the HDD / CDROM / USB to boot from. The active partition on that drive will be used. That's it.

Note:
I have a PC with 2 HDDs, too. BUT I have installed all the operating systems on the first one. And the second drive is for my data only. In my case I do need grub. I install it on some root partition and flash it on MBR. So that active partition does not matter at all.